# Correct order of the growth function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

$5 \log( \log n)  $

$n (\log n)^2$

$\sqrt{n} \log n$

$n^{\frac{4}{3}}$

$n \log (\log n)$

$7 \sqrt{n}$

What is the ascending order of the growth function? Please give the explanation as well.

Comment: What do you mean by correct order ?

Comment: from most efficient to least efficient

Comment: Do you have an idea of how any of them relate?

Comment: I know that logs are faster and fractional exponents are faster.But I don't have any depth of idea.Would you recommend something for a read?

Comment: Well, out of the 30 possible pairs, some of are clearly asymptotically bigger than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take sufficiently large value of n,then ascending order according to the value will be,
$5 log( log n)  < 7 \sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n} log n<n log (log n)<n (log n)^2<n^{\frac{4}{3}}$

So,if we sort them from Most efficient to least efficient,it will be

$5 log( log n)  > 7 \sqrt{n}>\sqrt{n} log n>n log (log n)>n (log n)^2>n^{\frac{4}{3}}$

Answer (score -1):

If we want for sufficient large n, then if we name the equation from top to down as from 1 to 6 then ordering looks like 1<5<2 , 7<3<2 and 6<4.